# Template tags in CKAN 2.4

Tags: jinja2, ckan

I am currently writing a CKAN extension. Now I need some custom tags in my HTML templates [as they are present in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/). The [CKAN documentation](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/theming/jinja-tags.html) is not exactly verbose on this topic. Does anybody know whether I can add custom tags in CKAN?

Answer (score 1):

The code that loads jinja and adds ckan's own custom tags is here:

https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/0b7aa77e5e38d1376050b638d19a88da67346ea6/ckan/config/environment.py#L216-L227

Check out the jinja docs to see if you can add to it once its created, which you could do from an extension. Otherwise, create a new plugin point and submit it as a PR.